# Dynamic Hyperlink to Row in Excel Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

I am needing to create a dynamic hyperlink in an Excel workbook to allow links between two related tables in separate sheets that will jump to the first row with the same reference in the related table. Whilst there are many examples available through various Excel forums and websites using a Google search and in Stackoverflow, none address the use in tables and as the range needs to change dynamically with the table depth, these aren't suitable and I haven't been able to convert the formulas to 'table notation'.

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure of the formula to hyperlink to a row in a related table is as follows:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address", INDEX(RelatedTableName[ColumnToSelect], MATCH([@ThisTableReferenceColumn], RelatedTableName[RelatedColumnName], 0), 1)), "Hyperlink Text")
```

I have created a sample file linking two tables in [GitHub](https://github.com/LlewopNomis/Dynamic-Hyperlink-to-Row-in-Excel-Table.git) that provides a concrete example if you are having trouble implementing this!